# Ef Core 3 The entity type XOrder cannot be mapped to a table because it is derived from Order Only base entity types can be mapped to a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

> Problem: We have Order entity with some inherit types such as : OnlineOrder , OfflineOrder , ...

```
public class Order 
{
    public Order()
    {
    }
    public virtual string Type { get; protected set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class OnlineOrder : Order
{
    public const string TypeName = "Online";
    public OnlineOrder() : base()
    {
    }
    public override string Type { get; protected set; } = TypeName;
    public OnlineType OnlineType { get; set; }
    public long FactorId { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; } = false;
}

public class OfflineOrder : Order
{
    public const string TypeName = "Offline";
    public OfflineOrder() : base()
    {
    }
    public override string Type { get; protected set; } = TypeName;
    public InputType InputType { get; set; }
    public long StoreId { get; set; }
}
```

and use this code in configuration of all entities:

```
public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable(typeof(TEntity).Name, Schema);
}
```

but when run migration get this exception:

```
The entity type 'OffineOrder' cannot be mapped to a table because it is derived from 'Order'. Only base entity types can be mapped to a table.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11811) and  [this breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#totable-on-a-derived-type-throws-an-exception) in ef core 3 `ToTable()` throw an exception because(**based breaking change link**):

> Starting with EF Core 3.0 and in preparation for adding TPT and TPC
>   support in a later release, `ToTable()` called on a derived type will
>   now throw an exception to avoid an unexpected mapping change in the
>   future.

So we change configuration class:

```
public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
{
    if (typeof(TEntity).BaseType == null)
        builder.ToTable(typeof(TEntity).Name, Schema);
}
```

Comment: So, do you know if EF Core 3.0 (or in my case 3.1.1) have support for TPT and TPC or not? Based on my current problem it seems to be not the case.

Comment: EF Core only has support for TPH (table-per-hierarchy). TPT support is a major feature planned for EF Core 5.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

Another cause is using `SetTableName` on a child entity (inherited from another entity). See [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18006#issuecomment-534366625)

Answer (score -2):

I got around this for now by calling modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable(null);

Comment: This is not a solution but a hack/workaround, please do not do this.